# Travelling from Winnipeg to YVR to Haneda to Sydney, multiple airlines -- Can I through-check baggage?

Tags: luggage, vancouver, sydney, winnipeg

Going to be travelling to Sydney in May from Winnipeg. It'll be an Air Canada flight from Winnipeg to Vancouver, then ANA Airlines to Haneda to Sydney. Am I able to through-check from Winnipeg's airport with Air Canada all the way to Sydney, or will I have to pick up my luggage in Vancouver and then check in again there because the airlines change? If so, how do I go about checking luggage for an international connection once I've arrived in Vancouver? Both airlines seem a little vague on if this process would work, and seeing as I'm only allowed one carry-on with ANA I'm going to *have* to check luggage, so I want to make sure I do it right and don't mess it up.

Will the same process apply to the return flight as well? Same locations. Also all on the same ticket.

Comment: Did you buy all of this on one ticket? Or do you have one ticket for the parts between Winnipeg and Vancouver and another one through to Sydney? Please edit your question to include this information. There's no need to write "Edit:", since most people who ever see your question will see it after that edit and won't care what it said before.

Comment: Thank you! Still new to this. It's all on the same ticket purchased together.

Answer (score 1):

Air Canada and ANA are partner airlines (see the list on [ANA's website](https://www.ana.co.jp/en/gb/serviceinfo/international/information/checkin.html)) and you're travelling on one ticket, so your bags will be checked all the way through in both directions.  As far as I can see, you don't need to pick up your bags in Japan to take them through customs, like you would in the US. You can confirm this with the check-in agent when you drop off your bags.

On your return trip, your bags will be checked through to Winnipeg but the Canada Border Services Agency guidance on [Arriving by Air](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/aba-apa-eng.html) rather unhelpfully says "You **may** [their emphasis] not be required to retrieve your baggage until your final destination." In Vancouver, you might have to pick up your bags, take them through customs and then give them back to the airline for Winnipeg (like in the US, if you're familiar with that), or the airline might transfer them without you needing to touch them. CBSA says you should ask your airline which applies. Ask when you check your bags in, in Australia.

You should check your booking for the rules about carry-on (and checked-in) luggage. It's not necessarily the case that you'll be restricted to the rules of the carrier for that particular flight: you might get the allowance of whatever airline you bought the ticket from, for the whole trip.